# Tripleplay Button and hover state with pointer

Tags: button, playn

is it possible to change the hover state of a Button, or the hover state of an ImageLayer, when hovering with the pointer ?

e.g.:

I hover on a Button and I change the color,or the alpha, or the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple Play is designed for touch interfaces, or at least to work equally well on touch and pointer based interfaces.

Thus it does not support hover, as hover is not possible in a touch interface.